# getFolderSize() error getting objects from a filled ArrayList<>

Tags: java, android-studio, arraylist

I'm trying to print the attributes of a Player object which are stored on an ArrayList. I created the objects and add them to the ArrayList, but at the time to get the index of it I'm getting a NullPointerExeption. I actually filled the ArrayList with 4 objects but I'm getting null. What am I missing here?

MainActivity.class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private ArrayList<Players> competitors = new ArrayList<>();
    private Tournament tournament;
    private String champion;
    private String table;
    private Integer score1;
    private Integer score2;
    private Random random = new Random();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Players players = new Players("Rodolfo",87, 1);
        Players players1 = new Players("Julian",78,1);
        Players players2 = new Players("Anastacio",89, 1);
        Players players3 = new Players("Ricardo", 93,1);

        competitors = new ArrayList<>();
        competitors.set(0,players);
        competitors.set(1,players1);
        competitors.set(2,players2);
        competitors.set(3,players3);

        Players i = competitors.get(1);

        Log.i("players names", i.getName());
}
```

Players.class:

```
public class Players {

    private String name;

    private Integer skill;

    private Integer luck;

    private String State;

    public Players(String name, Integer skill, Integer luck) {
        this.name = name;
        this.skill = skill;
        this.luck = luck;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getSkill() {
        return skill;
    }

    public void setSkill(Integer skill) {
        this.skill = skill;
    }

    public Integer getLuck() {
        return luck;
    }

    public void setLuck(Integer luck) {
        this.luck = luck;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return State;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        State = state;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.df.effect.conflict"
E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.torneotennis
E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
    Fail to get file list com.example.torneotennis
    getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.torneotennis, PID: 9614
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.torneotennis/com.example.torneotennis.MainActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

**UPDATE:** Using competitors.add(); also throws:

```
E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.df.effect.conflict"
E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.torneotennis
E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
    Fail to get file list com.example.torneotennis
    getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
```

**UPDATE 2:**  I debugged it, and the size of the `ArrayList<Players>` competitors is 4, as expected.

**UPDATE 3:** adding: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` does not fix the problem.

Comment: @Renis1235 you mean my MainActivity? Because its alredy posted, its the first one.

Comment: Check the answer below, that's the reason for your Exception. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68863313/7954021

Comment: @Renis1235 im still getting the error

Comment: @AgustínRabini it's a different error. Show us the code where `getFolderSize()` is invoked.

Comment: @bharathp im not executing `getFolderSize()` at anytime, im trying: `Players i = competitors.get(1);`

Comment: @AgustínRabini I would check with breakpoints at what line the error is thrown and try to go from there.

Comment: @bharathp i debugg it and the arrayList is been filled with size 4 wich is the spected. The problem comes when i try to get the array values

Answer (score 2):

The `NullPointerException` is due to the `set()` operation

```java
    competitors.set(0,players);
    competitors.set(1,players1);
    competitors.set(2,players2);
    competitors.set(3,players3);
```

Because `set()` is mainly used for replacing an existing element.

According to JAVA DOCS: 
*Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element (optional operation)*

Also, it throws `NullPointerException` if the specified element is `null` (So when you are doing `set()` operation the element at the specified index is `null`)

Use  `add()`  to add the element to list.

```java
    competitors.add(players);
    competitors.add(players1);
```

Comment: im still getting an error using add(). Thanks for answering

```E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array```
and
```E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.torneotennis```